# Changing data directory in scylla db causing error

Tags: scylla

I am trying to change data directory in Scylladb but I am getting following error:

**[shard 0] init - Directory '/mydir' cannot be initialized. Tried to do it but failed with: storage_io_error**

Could someone please help in fixing this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scylla requires XFS for data directory. Make sure it is the case.

Comment: But I am quite sure my scylladb directories are on ext4